# Что делает/как работает $save в angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Доброго времени суток, изучая работу с ресурсами в angular натолкнулся на слудеющий код:

```
var News,     //Ресурс
newsInstance; //Экземпляр новости

function updateNewsItem(){
    newsInstance.published = false;
    newsInstance.$save();
}

News = $resource('/api/news/:id/');
newsInstance = News.get({id: 3}, updateNewsItem); //Новость с id = 3, просто для примера
```

Не понимаю, как можно вызывать $save() без предварительного объявления.

Comment: Вам нужно еще прояснить вопросы как работает Javascript. Ну а по существу вопроса: после строчки *newsInstance = News.get({id: 3}, updateNewsItem);* newsInstance становится объектом, у которго есть функция *$save*

Answer (score 1):

В справке по [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) можно увидеть описание возвращаемого объекта:

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set contains these actions:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Когда данные вернулись с сервера, полученный объект будет объектом класса Resource и приведенные выше методы будут доступны у него с префиксом `$`.

Answer (score -2):

Метод `$save` содержится по умолчанию в конструкторе ресурсов и является доступным для вызова из экземпляра ресурса.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?